# Wireshark showing usernames and passwords from asp.net application in plain text

Tags: asp.net, https, wireshark, http-get

We have an ASP.NET web application which runs as a SAAS service, and end users use a standard browser like chrome to access it. It's a "single page application" architecture in that all GETS and POSTS are done from javascript and after pulling up the logon page, the browser page never refreshes.

A customer has recently emailed us to say that they visited the logon page and entered a dummy username and password, then they clicked the Logon button. They sent a Wireshark screenshot showing the username and password within a packet showing in clear text.

How could this ever be possible when the site only supports HTTPS/SSL ?

The packet looked like this:

```
Users_IP Our_SaaS_ServerIP HTTP2 838 HEADERS[23]: GET /w.ashx?....&username=USERNAMEINCLEARTEXT&password=PASSWORDINCLEARTEXT
```

When I try to reproduce this, I don't get to see any HTTP2 packets at all in wireshark, but I do see other packets between the client and server, so I'm not sure how the customer did this.

I would like to be able to reproduce this before I get back to the customer, but I only have basic experience with wireshark and handling packets like this.

I asked chatgpt and bard and both said it would be impossible to see a querystring if it was transmitting over SSL.

Comment: Thanks @Dai that puts my mind at ease! I'd like to reproduce this anyway though, can I get wireshark to behave this way easily ?

Comment: My comment reply was incorrect, I deleted it - turns out Wireshark decrypts TLS traffic completely differently: by using logged-keys or by knowing the private keys in-advance - I guess the reason they don't use the TLS certificate proxy attack is because it doesn't work with certificate-pinning - whereas using logged or saved keys is entirely undetectable to clients on that network.

Comment: All over my head :) I'm still not understanding how wireshark could read a javascript initiated http GET over an ssl connection. Are you saying roughly that wireshark will sniff the certificate handshake and use that information to decrypt future messages ? In which case wireshark must be sniffing at the time we first initiate contact with the website and not just on that particular http get ?

Comment: The user can set a systemwide environment variable (`SSLKEYLOGFILE`), which if set, instructs SSL/TLS libraries running on that computer to intentionally leak their private secret keys and save them to a file on-disk, and Wireshark can read that file and use that to read the keys and decrypt the traffic. Note this only works on TLS connections belonging to applications that are using specific TLS libraries that respect the `SSLKEYLOGFILE` setting.

Comment: In summary: if you configure Wireshark to decrypt HTTPS traffic, then you can see the contents in plaintext. That's not really something to be concerned about, as it requires the user actively configure the app on their machine to do that. It doesn't mean that others that don't have access to the machine can decrypt your traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments - much appreciated :)